# Selenium issue in using a function argument for send_keys value

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My issue involves using Selenium to take the values of a list and passing them to a WebElement with send_keys.

assuming `list_item_1` and `list_item_2` were imported via spreadsheet and `arg_1` and `arg_2` are a specific item of each list:

```
def run(arg_1, arg_2):
  driver.get(URL_TO_SITE)
  form_element_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('ELEMENT_ID')
  form_element_2 = driver.find_element_by_id('ELEMENT_ID')

  form_element_1.send_keys(arg_1)
  form_element_2.send_keys(arg_2)
  ...
  action.perform()
```

Running this gives the error:

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py",
>
> line 326, in send_keys
>   for i in range(len(val)):
>
> TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

This seems to be a problem isolated to using function arguments as the `send_keys` argument. Is there a workaround here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `arg_1` and `arg_2` are `WebElement` instances and you probably mean to send their **text** in `send_keys()`:

```
form_element_1.send_keys(arg_1.text)
form_element_2.send_keys(arg_2.text)
```

Comment: This was the issue. It was odd considering the arguments to the function were strings from a list.